# Using body parameters in a post Route with ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I am using ExpressJS/MongoDB on a NodeJS Runtime backend and I can't seem to figure out how I'd go about sending previous filled out form information to the next page to be used in the later steps in the form.  This is a multi-paged form.  For example, let's say I have a trial I am creating, and I input basic information such as trial name so it puts it into MongoDB and I move onto the next page.  Then I want to create subjects that are associated to the mongoDB object _id of the trial I just created on step 1 of filling out the form.  I can't seem to carry that data over to the next page on the App to use for each subject's document creation.  I am very new to NodeJS, any direction would be very helpful.

Here is my code for the new trial page on the trials.js route file:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const patient = require('../models/patients.js')
const trial = require('../models/trials.js')


//Create Trial Route
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const trial = new Trial({
        name: req.body.name,
        sponsor: req.body.sponsor,
        subjects: req.body.subjects,
        visits: req.body.visits,
        notes: req.body.notes,
        status: "Open"
        
    })
    try {
        const newTrial = await trial.save()
        res.render('subjects/new', {
            trialName: req.body.name,
            SubjectNum: req.body.subjects
        })
    } catch {
        res.render('trials/new', {
            trial: trial,
            errorMessage: "You must fill out all required form fields."
        })
    }
})
```

And here for the subject creation page on the patients.js route file:

```
//Create Subject Route
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    let existingTrial = await trial.findOne({name: req.body.trialName}).exec()
    console.log(existingTrial._id)
    const subjects = new subject({
        subject_num: req.body.subjectNum,
        subject_name: [{
            firstname: req.body.firstname,
            lastname: req.body.lastname
        }],
        subject_address: [{
            street: req.body.street,
            city: req.body.city,
            zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
            state: req.body.state
        }],
        notes: req.body.notes,
        trial: existingTrial._id
    })
    try {
        const newSubject = await subjects.save()
        res.render('subjects/new')
    } catch {
        res.render('subjects/new', {
            errorMessage: ""
        })
    }
})
```

Keep in mind I can traverse these pages just fine, but my mongoDB patient object will not save as it cannot see the subjectNum and trialName variable that i handed the view to render with.  I understand the view and the routes are two different things, I'm just unsure on how to let my POST route know what those variables are so it can use them to query the database for the trial id and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're not using any frontend framework or library. In this case, I'll suggest you store the data from each step in the browser's [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) then make a single post request to the server after the whole form is completed